# Insert values from one table to another if certain columns are unique from different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

The setup I have is the following I have to databases A and B on the same server. 
A and B have identical table names. I want to append data from tables of A to tables of B. However I want to append a certain row from A to B if and only if that row is unique on certain fields. For instance if i have table named People.

in A

People:

```
ID   name Surname
1    Mark Anthony 
2    Julius Ceasar 
3    Marcus Crassus
```

in B

People

```
ID   name   Surname 
1    Marcus Caelius
2    Julius Ceasar 
3    Sevilius Casca
4    Marcus Crassus
```

I want to add to the People table in B database those rows of People table in A where the name and surname fields do not already exist People of B.

so the result would be

in B

People

```
ID   name   Surname 
1    Marcus Caelius
2    Julius Ceasar 
3    Sevilius Casca
4    Marcus Crassus 
5    Mark Anthony
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just an `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into b.people(name, surname)
    select name, surname
    from a.people a
    where not exists (select 1 from b.people b where b.name = a.name and b.surname = a.surname);
```

This assumes that the `id` field is a serial/identity/auto increment column.  That is a best practice anyway.

You can also write this as:

```
insert into b.people(name, surname)
    select name, surname
    from a.people a
    except
    select name, surname
    from b.people b;
```

Comment: maybe but, a and b are not two different tables but two different databases, your answer assumes tables right?

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan . . . That doesn't really matter.  You just need to refer to the tables correctly.

Comment: what if There are many other columns is there no way in sql of iterating over them instead of naming each single one?

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan . . . Because the ids are different, I don't think there is a way without listing the columns.  You can use `except` rather than `not exists`, which is a slight simplification.